# Mouse doubleclick not work in textbox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to double click on the text box by which the text will be selected.....The code looks like

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    WebElement txtBoxElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));
    txtBoxElement.sendKeys("abc");
    System.out.println("Test start");
    Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
    Action a=builder.moveToElement(txtBoxElement).doubleClick(txtBoxElement).build();
    a.perform();

    //This is for another way to double click on the text field 

    Locatable locatable = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
    mouse.mouseMove(locatable.getCoordinates());
    mouse.doubleClick(locatable.getCoordinates());


    System.out.println("Test Complete");
}
```

but both of this way was not working I bypass this problem using this

```
    Action a=builder.moveToElement(txtBoxElement).sendKeys(txtBoxElement,Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a")).build();
    a.perform();
```

**my question is why double click is not working?**
I also try this for google search textbox it was also not working.
Here I want to mention one thing that I use Selenium 2.37 and firefox 26 .

I did not get any error but not double click on this element.I also observe that if I commented out the **txtBoxElement.sendKeys("abc");** part and then sendkeys using Actions event,it write the text on browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must be seeing following error while double clicking an element:

```
Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.
```

This is always issue with latest version of Firefox with latest verion of Selenium WebDriver(For more details please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922578/understanding-of-cannot-perform-native-interaction-could-not-load-native-event)).

You can resolve this issue by downgrading Firefox from 26 to 25.  With Firefox 25 your code will work.

Comment: I did not get any error but not double click on this element.I also observe that if I commented out the txtBoxElement.sendKeys("abc"); part and then sendkeys using Actions event then it write the text on browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have the Action statement incorrect for the double-click. I did a double-click with simple statements like this:

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);<br>
a.doubleClick(txtBoxElement);<br>
a.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select all of the text in the text box try:

```
WaitUntil.elementReady(driver, 2,".//span[@class='scale-input-box']/input").sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
```

To overcome problems with doubleclicking in Selenium [try Alternative workaround Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004164/perform-doubleclick-on-element-that-have-that/35004330)

Simplified to this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('map_container').dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick'));");
```