# Can't run Firefox capybara tests in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I recently set up my Windows 7 VM with everything needed to run my tests.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, rspec 3, selenium-webdriver 2.42.0, and capybara 2.4.1 gems.  Setting up on Windows was easier than I thought (even easier than on MacOS, maybe).

When running the tests in Firefox, I run into this error:

`Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.`

My tests run fine in Chrome for Windows.  My tests run fine in Chrome/Firefox on MacOS.

I've tried to disable native_events without any success:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.native_events = false
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :firefox, :profile => profile})
```

Any ideas?  Is there a way to update Firefox driver?  Am I missing an important installation on Windows?

Comment: Check out this SO answer, which may help explain why chrome is working but FF is not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922578/understanding-of-cannot-perform-native-interaction-could-not-load-native-event

Comment: I've tried disabling native events completely, but am still having issues in Firefox.  And why would this occur in Windows but not MacOS?

Comment: This is probably off topic, but reading about your problem made me realise that there was such thing as disabling and enabling native-events for Selenium firefox.
While u were trying to disable it, i had to enable it because I didnt realize it was false by default.
Life saver! My entire project's launch was saved after reading this! Thank you! :D